# ScrollView with ExpandableHeightGridView doesn't scroll

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext, scrollview, navigation-drawer

I want the homepage of my app to have different sections containing a list of items in every section. For this I have used a `ScrollView`. Inside the scrollview I have put a search area, and a `ExpandableHeightGridView` (this is a custom class that help the `GridView` to expand the space inside the `ScrollView` based on the number of items).

But regardless of this the scrollView doesn't work and search box appears at the top of the screen, meanwhile the `GridView` scrolls as if it wasn't inside ScrollView.

Below is my Code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/njoftime_background">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/event_background_block"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/search_area"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/njoftime_item_background">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/njoftime_main_color"
                        android:onClick="searchPressed"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/search_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_search"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:ems="20"

                        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/njoftime_desc"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:textSize="17sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/search_categories_area"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/search_area"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingTop="13dp">


                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/search_grid"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                        android:numColumns="4" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.example.crs.tempus.ExpandableHeightGridView
                    android:id="@+id/njoftime_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:numColumns="1" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"></ExpandableListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ExpandableHeightGridView

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

The ExpandableHeightGridView, is used also in another activity and it works.

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide screen shot how it looks currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your `ExpandableHeightGridView` class use below code inside your `onMeasure` override method. It works in my case.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
}
```

**Or**

2) In your code you might need to call `setExpanded` method of `ExpandableHeightGridView` class and set it to `true`.

Hope one of this solution would works for you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED---------

try to use a customScollview,create one CustomScrollview like this and use this

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

> android:fillviewport="true"

add this in your ScrollView ,like this

```
 <CustomScrollView
        android:fillviewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
```

Comment: I have used it and it doesn't work.  When I add the line above neither GridView doesn't scroll.

Comment: When I add the second solution only the GridView is scrollable. I don't know if the fact of using navigationDrawer has anything to do with it.